# Objective-C stop the inheritance flow for one method

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Let's say that `ParentClass` has a public initializer `initWithSomething`:

`-(id) initWithSomething: (NSString *)something;`

Now in `ChildClass`, I use this initializer, but I don't want anyone who extends `ChildClass` to have access to it. Instead I only want them to have access to my more specific initializer `initWithSomethingSpecific`.

So that `GrandChildClass` should ONLY have access to `initWithSomethingSpecific`, and NOT `initWithSomething`.

Is this possible in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you override the `ParentClass` method in `ChildClass` with a method which

1. cannot be called (easily), and
2. if called (by someone determined) denies it exists...

To achieve (1) you use the `unavailable` attribute, in `ChildClass.h` write something like:

```
// prevent use of inherited initWithSomething outside of this implementation
- (instancetype) initWithSomething:(Something *)something __attribute__((unavailable("Use -initWithSomethingSpecific: instead")));
```

This will stop Xcode providing it during code completion, and if a programmer writes it anyway will produce a compile-time error giving the message to use `initWithSomethingSpecific`.

To address (2) you provide an implementation of the method which calls `NSObject`'s `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`. For example in `ChildClass.m` write something like:

```
// prevent use of inherited initWithSomething outside of this implementation
- (instancetype) initWithSomething:(Something *)something
{
   [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]; // for any code which makes it here make it look like the method does not exist
   return nil;                           // will never reach here
}
```

(`_cmd` is a standard hidden argument to every Objective-C method whose value is the selector of the method itself.)

If this method is ever called the usual error and stack trace for an unimplemented method will be produced.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to enforce it, no.  You should document the use of the more specific initializer and leave it at that.  If you don't provide documentation then ensure you heavily comment the declaration in the header file.

If you are able to use the same method signature in `[ChildClass initWithSomething:]` then that will make `[ParentClass initWithSomething:]` impossible to get to in subclasses of `ChildClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `[ChildClass initWithSomething:]` return `nil`
then implement `initWithSomethingSpecific`

Comment: Wouldn't `initWithSomething` still be accessible, and just return `nil`?

Comment: Leading to run time errors ... I want the users to not see `initWithSomething` in the auto-complete.

Comment: @NathanH Yes, it will still be accessible. But your developer never get valid instance. They know shouldn't use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE` macro.
Put this code in your `ChildClass` header:

`- (instancetype)initWithSomething:(NSString *)something UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE;`

Also,
 if you need fully protection, you can implement `initWithSomething` in `ChildClass` with raising exception.